# How can I validate a SAML 2.0 Bearer Assertion to return an OAuth2 Bearer token for a web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0, owin

The environment that I'm working in uses [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.net/) to provide single sign on (SSO) capabilities and we want to update an application that is using basic authentication to be able to make use of the Shibboleth authentication to make API calls. Based upon my reading there are [specifications in process](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-19) but they don't appear to be widely supported. Currently we are using [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) in some other applications and would like to keep using that methodology. As such, is there a way that I can register and call a `/token` URI that will work correctly with the SAML 2.0 Bearer Assertion?

Answer (score 1):

You could customize Shibboleth IDP in such a way that it generates and returns an OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token valid in your environment. The token would be provided to your SP as an SAML attribute during single sign-on. Presuming you'll be using Shibboleth SP plugin for IIS for securing of your application, you could configure the SP to send the SAML attribute with the token to your application as an HTTP header and subsequently use it as a token in your API calls.

Shibboleth customization would be quite simple (implementation of a custom attribute generator). You would need to share cryptographic material (shared secrets/asymetric keys) from the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth server with your Shibboleth instance, so that it would be able to sign the tokens correctly.

Both Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth server and Shibboleth should be under your control for this approach to be securely applicable. If that is not the case Shibboleth could still be customized to request a token on behalf of your asp.net application (e.g. using Client Credentials grant) and then again provide it as a SAML attribute.

This approach is of course inverting your original idea of adding support for SAML tokens to Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth. My knowledge of C# ecosystem is limited, but it seems that [this project](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel) already includes extensions adding SAML 2 Bearer support to the owin library. See the [configuration extension](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/source/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin/AppBuilderExtensions/SamlBearerAuthenticationExtensions.cs) and an [example of usage](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/OWIN/TokenFormats/TokenFormatTest).